# Two Google Translator Widget for Responsive Layout

Tags: responsive-design, widget, google-translate

I recently faced an issue for adding one more GoogleTranslator widget in my web page. I did some research apparently Google won't allow more than one GoogleTranslator widget in template.

Does anyone have experienced the same issue? Is there any solution? In responsive Design I need to duplicate some blocks and use them in different orders.

Answer (score 1):

Create two container divs - one for your "normal" layout, one for your "mobile" layout (or more, depending on what you're doing). Have the widget start out inside of the "normal" layout's container.  Add some JavaScript to listen to the width of the window.  If it's under a certain break point (768px or less, 480px or less, etc.), move the widget to the other container div.

I've had this work for me - however the widget itself isn't responsive, so you'll have to deal with a new issue of the languages not fitting in the viewport.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As I said, I can't use another block even when I changed id names. That's the problem. anyway I managed to style it differently with some media queries and just calling GTranslator api once. There is no solution for two widget on the same page.

Comment: My solution doesn't have multiple widgets, it's ONE widget, but we move it to a new container element with JavaScript based on the dimensions of the window.  So in your mobile layout, the widget's parent will be #Parent_1, and if you enlarge the window to full-screen (or to the next break point), our script moves it so that its parent element is #Parent_2.

I have it working on 3 websites successfully, so I know it works.

Anyway, sounds like you have figured out a way to do what you need using CSS, which is a better solution IMO.  You should post your solution so that you can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Found this post while doing a quick search for what is possibly a duplicated question on the site that I just answered, however will post an answer incase someone else ends up here for a solution.

Jump to solution: http://jsfiddle.net/melfy/15zr6ov0/

More details and code on my another stack overflow response:

> [Is there any way for more than one Google Translate widget to be loaded on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667822/is-there-any-way-for-more-than-one-google-translate-widget-to-be-loaded-on-a-pag/51761598#51761598)

---

Fiddle code contains (with jquery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html 

PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Google Translate</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header" style="background-color: #ddd;">
        <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

        This is a header

    </div>

    <p> This is some text that should be translated </p>


    <div id="footer" style="background-color: #ddd;">
        This is your footer

        <div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// store google translate's change event
trackChange = null;
pageDelayed = 3000;

// overwrite prototype to snoop, reset after we find it (keep this right before translate init)
Element.prototype._addEventListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(a,b,c) {
  reset = false;

  // filter out first change event
  if (a == 'change'){
    trackChange = b;
    reset = true;
  }

  if(c==undefined)
    c=false;

  this._addEventListener(a,b,c);

  if(!this.eventListenerList)
    this.eventListenerList = {};

  if(!this.eventListenerList[a])
    this.eventListenerList[a] = [];

  this.eventListenerList[a].push({listener:b,useCapture:c});

  if (reset){
    Element.prototype.addEventListener = Element.prototype._addEventListener;
  }
};


function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en' }, 'google_translate_element');

  let first = $('#google_translate_element');
  let second = $('#google_translate_element2');

  let nowChanging = false;

  // we need to let it load, since it'll be in footer a small delay shouldn't be a problem
  setTimeout(function(){
    select = first.find('select');
    // lets clone the translate select
    second.html(first.clone());
    second.find('select').val(select.val());

    // add our own event change
    first.find('select').on('change', function(event){
      if (nowChanging == false){
        second.find('select').val($(this).val());
      }
      return true;
    });

    second.find('select').on('change', function(event){
      if (nowChanging){
        return;
      }

      nowChanging = true;
      first.find('select').val($(this).val());
      trackChange();

      // give this some timeout incase changing events try to hit each other                    
      setTimeout(function(){
        nowChanging = false;
      }, 1000);

    });
  }, pageDelayed);
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me.  Add the following to your CSS:

```
#google_translate_element img
{
width: auto !important;
}
```

You may have to rename the container based on what's in your structural code.