# Is there any way for more than one Google Translate widget to be loaded on a page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, widget, google-translate

Is there any way possible to load a Google Translate widget in the sidebar and one in the footer, for example.

Every way I've tried has only loaded so that both appear in the location of the first instance on the page.

Comment: You can't have more than one Google Translator in a page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering I kinda felt obligated to solve the puzzle! You can skip to the good part by checking out the jsfiddle: (it works as of now but knowing google it might not tomorrow)

http://jsfiddle.net/melfy/15zr6ov0/

---

Lets begin:

First google translate is loaded and adds a listener for a select box it adds to the DOM after you call the right element but we need that change event to call a change for a select box we're going to clone from the original one to get google to update the translation, this gets a bit messy as we over take the prototype (which is usually bad practice)

Start by adding your header element:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Then we add our footer element:

```
<div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
```

Next we pull in the google translator

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Now we get to the good part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// store google translate's change event
trackChange = null;
pageDelayed = 3000;

// overwrite prototype to snoop, reset after we find it (keep this right before translate init)
Element.prototype._addEventListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(a,b,c) {
  reset = false;

  // filter out first change event
  if (a == 'change'){
    trackChange = b;
    reset = true;
  }

  if(c==undefined)
    c=false;

  this._addEventListener(a,b,c);

  if(!this.eventListenerList)
    this.eventListenerList = {};

  if(!this.eventListenerList[a])
    this.eventListenerList[a] = [];

  this.eventListenerList[a].push({listener:b,useCapture:c});

  if (reset){
    Element.prototype.addEventListener = Element.prototype._addEventListener;
  }
};


function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en' }, 'google_translate_element');

  let first = $('#google_translate_element');
  let second = $('#google_translate_element2');

  let nowChanging = false;

  // we need to let it load, since it'll be in footer a small delay shouldn't be a problem
  setTimeout(function(){
    select = first.find('select');
    // lets clone the translate select
    second.html(first.clone());
    second.find('select').val(select.val());

    // add our own event change
    first.find('select').on('change', function(event){
      if (nowChanging == false){
        second.find('select').val($(this).val());
      }
      return true;
    });

    second.find('select').on('change', function(event){
      if (nowChanging){
        return;
      }

      nowChanging = true;
      first.find('select').val($(this).val());
      trackChange();

      // give this some timeout incase changing events try to hit each other                    
      setTimeout(function(){
        nowChanging = false;
      }, 1000);

    });
  }, pageDelayed);
}
</script>
```

You can change the pageDelayed variable to trigger quicker or slower but if it's in your footer, bumping it up to delay longer may help it work more efficiently depending on your page load

Comment: Mate you're a genius, I'd hired about a dozen different devs trying to get this done.  Cheers for that!

Comment: Alas, although you managed to get 2 translate <select> elements to appear, the change event is changing both header, footer and the text in the middle. You were right to be skeptical about the longevity of the solution. Great effort though :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not have the widget be loaded more than once in a single page. Google just doesn't allow for that. One potential workaround would be putting the code in an iFrame and then putting two iFrames onto your webpage.

Create a file called iframe.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</head>
<body>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit(){
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

In your other file put code something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title>Google Translate</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?b=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header" style="background-color: red;">
    <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
    <strong>A</strong>
</div>

<div id="footer" style="background-color: blue;">
    <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
    <strong>B</strong>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can provide an example of adding the google translate code to an iframe correctly I'd be happy to award the bounty to you

Comment: Ok. Will do. Give me a few minutes.